# BOTs C&C channels

Tags: authentication, public-key-infrastructure, botnet

Can someone please explain the C&C for bots ?
im reading a  [paper](http://static.usenix.org/event/leet11/tech/full_papers/Xiang.pdf)  about Android bot  , and its explaining something called URL flux 
as method of C&C . however i couldn't really get it , so  i need to know how normal bots preform c&c so i can understand this .
for example why the bot needs a public key to authenticate commands ? and what the username generator  algorithm for ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two questions in there, and these are well documented in various places, but let me have a quick stab at it:

- you don't want your bot taking commands from the wrong place, so you need an authentication mechanism. Public/Private key pairs provide an easy, scalable mechanism
- it helps to be able to keep unique id's for all bots so you can address them or seems specific commands

Traditionally the C&C had been the weakest point as if it was taken out the botnet would fail, so improvements included using a selection of URLs, and URLFlux takes that a step further.

Answer (score 4):

Fastflux is a technique in which DNS records are change constantly for a given C&C server. With botnet C&C server have a DNS name rather then the IP address, if anyone of the C&C server is taken down it can be immediately move down to different IP address. So this technique practically makes impossible to take down a complete botnet.